# How to find size of a queue in LinkedQueue.java without a counter variable

Tags: variables, size, counter

So for a project I have to create a LinkedQueue class but without a counter variable so I can't exactly keep track of how many elements are in the queue.
I need to create a size method to return the number of elements in the queue but I have no idea how to do it...here's my code:

```
package animal;
import exceptions.EmptyQueueException;

/**
* @author Sharon Umute 
* Comp 139 001B
*/
public class LinkedQueue<T> implements QueueADT<T>{

SinglyLinkedNode<T> tail,head;

public LinkedQueue(){
    head=tail=null;
}

@Override
public void enqueue(T element) {
    SinglyLinkedNode<T> node =new SinglyLinkedNode<T>(element); 
    if(isEmpty()){
        head = node;
    }else{
        tail.setNext(node);
    }
    tail=node;
}

@Override
public T dequeue() throws EmptyQueueException {
    if (isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyQueueException("queue");
    }else{
        T result = head.getElement();
        head=head.getNext();

        if(isEmpty()){
            tail=null;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

@Override
public T first() throws EmptyQueueException {
    if (isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyQueueException("queue");
    }else{
        T result=head.getElement();
        return result;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return(head.getElement()==null);
}

@Override
public int size() {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is should be a good way to implement size method:

```
   Iterator it = this.head.iterator();
   int i = 0;

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
       LinkedQueue node = it.Next();
       i++;
    }
    return i;
```